# Jest Test dont work in animation test with multiple animated view with react-native-animated

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to create a group of keys that when a button is pressed, those keys with the back side rotate and show the other side of them. It works normally when the app starts, but in the test for some reason it doesn't change when I put a certain number of new keys in the data.

An example code below, containing the tested component and the test.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { render, fireEvent, renderHook, screen } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  interpolate,
  SharedValue,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const mapao = [
  {
    key: '0',
    frontKey: {
      value: 'value0front',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value0front',
      acessibilityHint: 'value0front',
    },
    backKey: {
      value: 'value0back',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value0back',
      acessibilityHint: 'value0back',
    },
  },
  {
    key: '1',
    frontKey: {
      value: 'value1front',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value1frontAcess',
      acessibilityHint: 'value1frontAcess',
    },
    backKey: {
      value: 'value1back',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value1backAcess',
      acessibilityHint: 'value1backAcess',
    },
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    frontKey: {
      value: 'value2front',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value2front',
      acessibilityHint: 'value2front',
    },
  },
];

const mapao1 = [
  {
    key: '0',
    frontKey: {
      value: 'value0front',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value0front',
      acessibilityHint: 'value0front',
    },
    backKey: {
      value: 'value0back',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value0back',
      acessibilityHint: 'value0back',
    },
  },
  {
    key: '1',
    frontKey: {
      value: 'value1front',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value1frontAcess',
      acessibilityHint: 'value1frontAcess',
    },
    backKey: {
      value: 'value1back',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value1backAcess',
      acessibilityHint: 'value1backAcess',
    },
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    frontKey: {
      value: 'value2front',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value2frontAcess',
      acessibilityHint: 'value2frontAcess',
    },
    backKey: {
      value: 'value2back',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value2backAcess',
      acessibilityHint: 'value2backAcess',
    },
  },
  {
    key: '4',
    frontKey: {
      value: 'value4front',
      onPress: () => 'oi',
      acessibilityLabel: 'value4front',
      acessibilityHint: 'value4front',
    },
  },
];

interface Props {
  sharedValue: SharedValue<number>;
  mapao: typeof mapao;
}

const AnimatedSharedValueComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const flipValue = props.sharedValue;

  const frontAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const flipVal = interpolate(flipValue.value, [0, 1], [0, 180]);
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          rotateY: withTiming(`${flipVal}deg`, { duration: 500 }),
        },
      ],
      zIndex: flipValue.value ? 1 : 2,
    };
  }, []);

  const backAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const flipVal = interpolate(flipValue.value, [0, 1], [180, 360]);
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          rotateY: withTiming(`${flipVal}deg`, { duration: 500 }),
        },
      ],
      zIndex: flipValue.value ? 2 : 1,
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        accessibilityHint="button"
        onPress={() => {
          flipValue.value = flipValue.value ? 0 : 1;
        }}>
        value
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {props?.mapao?.map(({ frontKey, backKey, key }) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={key}>
            {backKey?.value && (
              <View>
                <Animated.View
                  style={[
                    {
                      position: 'absolute',
                      backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
                      width: 40,
                      height: 80,
                      backgroundColor: 'black',
                      margin: 30,
                    },
                    frontAnimatedStyle,
                  ]}>
                  accessibilityLabel={frontKey.acessibilityLabel}
                  accessibilityHint={frontKey.acessibilityHint}
                  <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      testID="key_button"
                      accessibilityRole="button"
                      accessibilityLanguage="pt-BR"
                      onPress={frontKey.onPress}>
                      <Text>{frontKey.value}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </Animated.View>

                <Animated.View
                  style={[
                    {
                      backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
                      width: 40,
                      height: 80,
                      backgroundColor: 'black',
                      margin: 30,
                    },
                    backAnimatedStyle,
                  ]}
                  accessibilityLabel={backKey.acessibilityLabel}
                  accessibilityHint={backKey.acessibilityHint}>
                  <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      testID="key_button"
                      accessibilityRole="button"
                      accessibilityLanguage="pt-BR"
                      onPress={backKey.onPress}>
                      <Text>{backKey.value}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </Animated.View>
              </View>
            )}
            {!backKey?.value && (
              <View
                style={[
                  {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
                    width: 40,
                    height: 80,
                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                    margin: 30,
                  },
                ]}
                accessibilityLabel={frontKey.acessibilityLabel}
                accessibilityHint={frontKey.acessibilityHint}>
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    testID="key_button"
                    accessibilityRole="button"
                    accessibilityLanguage="pt-BR"
                    onPress={frontKey.onPress}>
                    <Text>{frontKey.value}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

describe('Tests of animations', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  test('withTiming animation, define shared value outside component', () => {
    const backStyle = {
      transform: [{ rotateY: '360deg' }],
      zIndex: 2,
    };

    let sharedValue: SharedValue<number>;
    renderHook(() => {
      sharedValue = useSharedValue(0);
    });

    render(
      // @ts-expect-error TypeScript doesn't understand that renderHook defined sharedValue;
      <AnimatedSharedValueComponent sharedValue={sharedValue} mapao={mapao} />,
    );
    const view = screen.getByAccessibilityHint('value1backAcess');
    const button = screen.getByAccessibilityHint('button');

    fireEvent.press(button);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(600);
    expect(view).toHaveAnimatedStyle(backStyle);
  });
});
```

with the array mapao the test miraculously passes, but with the array mapao1, the code does not. Leading me to believe about some sort of limitation on the number of animateds. I have no idea what happens, as I only increased the number of item on each date. I wish someone could help me.

In the test, follow what was mentioned in the reanimated documentation and github about tests, it passes with a data type (mapao), but does not pass with another type (mapao1).

My versions of Reanimated, React and React Native are:

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
"@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.2",
"@testing-library/react-native": "^12.1.3"
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/jestSetupFile.ts'],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.svg": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/svgrMock.js"
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|react-native-reanimated)/)',
  ],
};
```

jestSetupFile.ts

```
jest.mock(
  '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage',
  () => require('@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock') as unknown,
);
import { setUpTests } from 'react-native-reanimated/src/reanimated2/jestUtils';
setUpTests();
import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect';
```

Any more info I'm willing to give, but I can't show you the actual code.